# Using Miniprofiler with Neo4j Graph DB

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I'm playing around with [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/) community edition, with [Neo4jClient](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient) for .net, and looking for a way to use the great [Miniprofiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) for the calls to the Neo4j DB.

I'm using the miniprofiler on some other projects with SQL Server and Entity Framework and getting wonderful insights about the queries sent to the DB. Wondering if I can get the same with Neo4j and Cypher queries.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No and Maybe.

**No**, as it doesn't exist at the moment.

**Maybe** as you could either have a stab at writing it yourself, or add it as a feature request to the Neo4jClient GitHub page and we can have a look about doing it in the future, but obvs it comes after bolt and a few other things.